# What does "-" mean in this "-cp" command?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, make

I came across this in one of Android makefiles ([build/core/Makefile](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_build/blob/caf/cm-12.1/core/Makefile#L868)):

```
$(hide) -cp $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)/init.recovery.*.rc $(TARGET_RECOVERY_ROOT_OUT)/
```

What does the `-` mean in front of `cp` here? It probably has something to do with suppressing errors but I couldn't google documentation for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`-` in a recipe tells Make to ignore any errors (see [Errors in recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html#Errors)).

In this specific case, any error reported by `cp` will be ignored (the output will contain any messages, but the build will continue).

This only works if `-` is interpreted by Make, *i.e.* it's the first non-whitespace character in the line (or the characters preceding it are also interpreted by Make). In this case, `$(hide)` needs to be considered: if `hide` is empty or `@`, `-cp` will have the intended effect; but if `hide` is for instance `@>/dev/null` (so the command isn't echoed and its standard output is discarded), `-cp` will be passed as-is to the shell and the command will fail.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think it was a make thing. For some reason it didn't work last two times I tried to build CyanogenMod, I guess that's why they replaced it with a `|| true` at the end.

Comment: Yeah, `$(hide)` probably messes things up, the `-` is supposed to be the first character after the tab.

Comment: @szx another option is `|| :` at the end.